# Should I treat my own single underscored attributes as private?

Tags: python

If I use a single leading underscore for an attribute in a class, would it be wrong of me to access it from a different object? Is a single underscore saying "I will use this as I please but you the user shouldn't touch it" or should even the developer treat it as though it were private?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should refrain from doing so as much as reasonably possible because it breaks encapsulation which one of the benefits of the object-oriented paradigm. While some feel it's fine as certain higher levels of scoping, say module or package, I've found avoiding doing so a useful rule-of-thumb even within the various methods of a single class -- at least if it's fairly complicated, subtle, or just an aspect I think I might want to change later.

The reason is every time you do something with one, you're creating a dependency between one object's internals and where you're coding, be it another part of the same object or module or whatever. The more of this there is, the harder it will be later to maintain or enhance things.

Another aspect to consider is the fact that whenever you feel a need to do so, it may be indicative of a need for a better design -- in which cause you can treat it a warning sign and react accordingly.

Creating an interface for doing operations that deal with internal details often means having to design and implement more code than not doing so would. So in each case, the benefits must be weighed against the costs to determine if it's worth it. Eventually experience (and education if it's ongoing) makes such decisions easier maybe even instinctual.

Comment: I think this is what I normally do. Usually I never break encapsulation in this way but in this case it would make my code much more complex so I'll access the single-underscored attribute from outside the class.

Comment: @MikeVella: That's fine, I'm not saying one should _never_ ever do it, only that the various trade-offs are considered (and understood) within the context of whatever you're doing. Also, Python makes it a little easier than some languages to go back later and retrofit something -- by adding descriptors, for example.

Answer (score 6):

The single underscore indicates that it's not for *public* consumption; code within the same package is welcome to poke and prod it.